# AttributeError at /home/: 'ActionCodeForm' object has no attribute 'is_bound'

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I'm creating a home page for my Django webapp, outside of Django admin. I'd like the home page to have a very simple ModelForm that when submitted, writes to the database.

I'm getting the following error at /home/ currently and not sure how to resolve it.

> AttributeError at /home/ 'ActionCodeForm' object has no attribute
>   'is_bound'

I know about bound and unbound forms and have read the docs, but I am not sure how to actually implement them.

Here is my model:

```
class ActionCode(models.Model):
    action_code = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10,
                                   verbose_name="Action Code")
```

Here is my `ModelForm`:

```
class ActionCodeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActionCode
        fields = ('action_code',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActionCodeForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my view:

```
def action_code_form(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ActionCodeForm()
    else:
        form = ActionCodeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        action_code = form.cleaned_data['action_code']
        form.save()
    else:
        form = ActionCodeForm()
    return render('action_code_form.html', {'form': form},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is my template, `action_code_form.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And `urls.py`:

```
from home.views import action_code_form

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', action_code_form, name="home"),
]
```

Comment: I don't know if it's related or maybe just a typo, but it should be `super(ActionCodeForm, self)`, not `super(ActionCodeForm)`.

Comment: This implies that your form is never being used at all, since that would be a TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the form is valid only if the method is `POST`. Also, the first param of `render()` must be `request`

Your view should be as follows:

```
def action_code_form(request):
    form = ActionCodeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            action_code = form.cleaned_data['action_code']
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'action_code_form.html', {'form': form})
```

If you need to override `__init__()` in your model form, then you should add `self` as a second parameter to `super()` (there is no need to keep the following two lines if you do not have any specific behavior that you want to add to your form):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ActionCodeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: But really, there's no need to override `__init__` at all, if all you're going to do is call the superclass method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I meant just if he wants to add some custom behavior in it, like initializing the form or something like that.

Comment: Note that `is_valid()` simply [returns`self.is_bound and not self.errors`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L169), so what the OP does might be a bit convoluted, but it's not wrong. On a GET request, the form is unbound, and `is_valid()` will simply return `False`.